# Is there a faster way to test RAM than memtest86+?

Tags: memory, memtest86+, memtest

I have a couple of PCs with 8GB of RAM and for quick checks I'm using an Ubuntu live CD, but in case of troubles I have to resort to memtest86+. However, memtest86+ is taking quite a while to complete.

Is there a faster way to test RAM?

**Update**

From the changelog for version 5:

- Optimized run time for faster memory error detection

Comment: When testing critical hardware, your goal should not be speed. It should be thoroughness. A single pass of Memtest86+ on 8GB DDR3-1333 dual channel RAM takes about an hour for me, but the last time I had RAM problems they could only be diagnosed with overnight tests. Repeated overnight tests.

Comment: It's true, overnight tests are rarely avoidable. I was hoping for some tools optimized for a given chipset and/or CPU.

Comment: @alexandrul - What you want to do makes no sense if your attempting to locate "bad memory" the entire point of memtest86+ is to test every single possible value.  Since 8GB is about 8 billion bits a single pass will take awhile.  What sort of tools you were expecting is confusing, DDR3 memory is DDR3 memory the chipset its on isn't really a factor.

Comment: Quick check is replace the memory with known good modules.

Comment: @Ramhound: not so easy. I'm using memtest86+ on both Pentium 4 systems with DDR1, and i5 with DDR3. I just want to be sure that I get the maximum available test speed on both architectures.

Answer (score 7):

No. But you can stop memtest after Test 6. If everything passed until this moment, there are high chances your memory chips are OK.

Note that memtest doesn't work on some Macs.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, previously I was using test #5 for quick checks before leaving it running for the night.